# Android Databinding not update UI immediately in RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-databinding

I have a recyclerView and each list item view contains two views -

- a text view to show some text from POJO using databinding lib and
- a button when that button is clicked, it calls method from viewmodel.

The viewmodel changes the text directly to the POJO. Every thing works fine except the recycler view needs to be refreshed to show changes.

My POJO

```
public class Post{
private String title;
...getter and setter
}
```

Recycler Adatper is something like this.

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Post> posts;
...
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final ViewDataBinding binding;

    public MyViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    void bindView(int position) {
        Post post = posts.get(position);
        binding.setVariable(BR.post, post);
        binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, myViewModel);
        binding.executePendingBindings();

    }
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.post_list_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindView(position);
}
...
}
```

post_list_item.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <variable
        name="post"
        type="....Post" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="....MyViewModel"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{post.title}" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClickListener="@{()->viewModel.onButtonClicked(post)}"
/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and viewModel has this method.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
 public void onButtonClicked(Post post) {
post.setTitle("some text");
}
```

I think there is a way to change the UI immediately when the data in POJO is changed. But now I need to draw the recycler view off the screen or rotate the screen.

Comment: You can use [`ObservableField`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField) or extend POJO from [`BaseObservable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable) - it can help you update view  with binding immediately. Another way to do it, using `LiveData` or directly calling `adapter.notifyItemChanged()`.

Comment: @ConstOrVar thank you. You really save my day. Using ObservableField or Calling adapter's method do what I want. If you have time and patient, may I know which one is better in terms of Performance and Maintenance? Extending POJO from BaseObservable is a little off for me as the POJO may need to extend other class in future.

Comment: `adapter.notifyItemChanged()` - it's more universal approach, which trigger `onBindViewHolder()` under the hood. On the other hand, `BaseObservable/ObservabeField` set listeners on particular properties or the whole object - but the cost is creating separate model (extending origin). Personally, if I'm using data binding in layout and want change several items at a time (multi edit mode), I use `ObservableField`. If I need change only one item at a time, I prefer `adapter.notifyItemChanged()`.  For me, it's not performance based decision, but convenience of development process.